# Discrete Mathematics - Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Let $UH = \{0, 1\}$. For each of the following formulae charaterize their models (tell what needs to be true for the formulae to be true).

1. $\forall X(p(X,0,X))$
2. $\forall X\exists Y(p(X,Y,0))$
3. $\exists Y\forall X(p(X,Y,0))$

$UH$ refers to the Universe of Discourse.

While my tutor has already gone through the answer and explanation to this question, I still do not understand how this questions is to be interpreted and answered. For example, what does the "$p$" mean? And the letters and zeroes in the parentheses?

This question comes under the topic of Logic in my Discrete Mathematics course. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Well the $0$ could stand for falsity. But I think your teacher has to tell you what $p$ means?

Answer (score 0):

$p$ is a **predicate** function with three arguments in the universe of discourse.   That is, it takes three entities as inputs and outputs True or False.

$X, Y$ are **entities** in the universe of discourse.  That is, they are variables which may have values of within the universe of discourse.

$0, 1$ are values within the **universe of discourse**, $\mathcal{UH}$.   Specifically, they are the only possible values any entities within *this* universe may take.  That is what is meant by:  $\mathcal{UH} = \{0, 1\}$

$\forall, \exists$ are quantifiers for the entities.  $\forall$ is the **universal quantifier**, meaning that the statement holds for all values of the given entity.  $\exists$ is the **existential quantifier**, meaning that the statement holds for some values of the given entity (that is: at least one, and maybe more).

*Note* that the order of the quantifiers is important.  Changing the order of quantifiers changes the *meaning* of the statement.  $\forall X, \exists Y$ means that for all values of X their is at least one value of Y where the statement holds; though this may be a different Y value for each value of X.  $\exists Y, \forall X$ means that their is at least one value of Y where the statement holds for all X (and that *same* Y value).

So, for instance: $\forall X\bigl( p(X,0,X) \bigr)$ means that both $p(0,0,0)$ and $p(1,0,1)$ are true.